# Filtrar Loop WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Como posso filtrar o loop no WordPress? Preciso criar vários loop com filtros diferentes. Exemplo: Extrair o último post da categoria x.

Answer (score 2):

Não é muito claro o que você quer. O loop é só uma iteração sobre um conjunto de posts vindos de uma consulta:

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
    }
}
```

No caso dos loops "originais" de cada página, essa consulta é feita pelo core e o objeto é guardado na global `$wp_query`.

Se o que você quer é não exibir o último post de cada página você pode dentro do loop pular aquela iteração:

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        // pula o último post da página atual
        if( $wp_query->current_post + 1 === $wp_query->post_count ) {
            continue;
        } 
    }
}
```

Agora se você quer retirar um post X da lista de posts antes de rodar o loop, pode usar o hook [**`pre_get_posts`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) pra isso.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer consultas à base de dados do Wordpress utilize a classe WP_Query. Se quiser o último post, por ex:

`$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );`

Você pode utilizar diversos parâmetros para a consulta como "author" ou "category", além de ordenar pela opção "oderby".

Veja a doc completa: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query